# Bad parse with interpolated strings separated by a dot?

Tags: vlang

I went to print a version number like *v3.14* and got this:

```
version.v:218:30: error: unexpected `$2`, expecting `name` 
  216 |     ver1 := (x >> 24) & 0xFF
  217 |     ver2 := (x >> 16) & 0xFF
  218 |     println('Version v$ver1.$ver2')
      |                                 ^
```

The solution was to put braces around `ver1` in the `println` to avoid the bad parse. I think I understand why it's happening (the dot makes the parse think it has a compound name), but I would have thought the dollar sign on `ver2` would have prevented that.

(yes, not much of a question)

Answer (score 3):

The dot makes the parser continue parsing an expression. The parser then sees `$` and `ver2` tokens and these do not form an valid expression, so you get an error. (Note e.g. `$` may be the start of a valid expression in V).

Either of these will work instead:

```
    println('Version v${ver1}.$ver2')
    println('Version v$ver1\.$ver2') // escape the dot
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do this. So that it doesn't not think `ver2` to be a part of `ver1`.

```
println('Version v${ver1}.${ver2}')
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. That's what I noted in my "question". It just surprised me that `$ver2` could ever be though of as a method of `$ver1`. A method name that starts with a dollar-sign? Double evaluation somehow? Anyway, all is good!